# A nontrivial topological module that is not a vector space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry

A nontrivial topological module that is not a vector space?

Hello all. I would greatly appreciate some help with topological modules; they lie at the intersection of two areas that are both relatively new to me, namely topology and algebraic structures, and I have trouble conceptualising them.

I am looking for a concrete example of a topological module with the following properties:

1) The topology of the module is T1 (and, ideally, Fréchet-Urysohn).

2) The topology of the ring is not discrete.

3) The module is not a vector space.

I can easily come up with topological modules satisfying (1,2) or (1,3), and a colleague has given me an example that satisfies (2,3) [Take the ring of polynomials $R[x]$ and quotient by the ideal generated by $x^2$; for the topology, a set $X$ is open iff for every $x\in X$ and for every $e$ with $e^2=0$ we have $x+e\in X$]. But I need a construction that satisfies all 3.

The reason I'm asking is because I have a result about (something like) topological vector spaces which would also hold in a trivial manner about (something like) a topological module over a ring with the discrete topology, but might not in general hold for a topological module. I can't think of any simple examples, though, and I have some difficulty moving forward purely in the abstract. I'm only concerned with Fréchet-Urysohn topologies, but at least I'd like something that's T1.

I suspect that the answer might come from algebraic geometry (a polynomial ring acting on itself perhaps?) which I'm even less familiar with, so I've added the relevant tag.

Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take any topological ring whose topology satisfies whatever conditions you want which does not contain a field, and consider it as a module over itself. For concreteness you can consider the [$p$-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with their usual profinite topology.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, take any commutative noetherian ring $R$ and any ideal $I$ contained in the *Jacobson radical* of $R$. Put on any finitely generated $R$-module $M$ the $I$-adic topology, for which a fundamental system of neighbourhoods of $0$ is
$$\{ I^nM\mid n\in\mathbf N\}$$
This  topology is *Hausdorff* (`T2`) and it is the `discrete topology` if and only if  $\;I^nM=\{0\}$ for  some $n$.